# Is it possible to transform a value between view and model in AngularJS for input?

Tags: angularjs

New to AngularJS.  Trying to figure out how I would accomplish this, or if it is possible at all.

I know I can bound a value to the input box by using

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myvalue">
```

But what if I want it such that the value between the model and the view is transformed?

For example, for currency, I like to store my value in cents.  However, I want to allow my users to enter dollar amounts.  So I need to convert the value by a factor of 100 between the view and controller, i.e. in the model I would have 100, and in the view, I would have 1.

Is that possible?  If so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: This answer might help you achieve what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15902274/992040

Answer (score 52):

I ran into the same problem as you. I started using wciu's solution but ran into an issue where the values would flicker between the cents and dollars. I ended up hooking into the pipeline that is used to do the binding between view and model.

```
merchantApp.directive('transformTest', function() {
  return { restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      if(ngModel) { // Don't do anything unless we have a model

        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
          return value*100;
        });

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
          return value/100;
        });

      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example on how you use this solution in the view?

Comment: Thanks! The best solution so far. @theDmi you need to include this directive on your input field.

Comment: Thanks - I'm also doing dollars-to-cents (cents internally, dollars for the users) and used this, calling it "dollarsToCents".  (I also added some .toFixed() calls internally as I was getting rounding errors).

As for using it in the HTML, this worked:

`<input ng-model="item.unit_price_cents" dollars-to-cents="true">`

Comment: For me, pushing the formatters as a number conflicted with ng-maxlength. This fixed it: `(value / 100).toString()`

Comment: i expected a solution using pipes like `<input type="number" ng-model="myvalue | converter">`. Isn't it possible to do this?

Comment: @LuckyLikey The problem with using a filter (the angular term for the operator on the right on the pipe character) for this sort of thing is that it's only one-directional; it will change the value coming from the model to the view, but it won't convert back, and for this reason I don't think filters are supported at all on ngModel

Answer (score 8):

I would just use Object.defineProperty to solve this problem, for example:

```
var prop = 0;
Object.defineProperty($scope, "prop", {
    get: function () {
        return prop / 100;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        prop = parseInt(value) * 100;
    }
});
```

The variable prop is now always = $scope.prop * 100.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [ngChange](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput) optional method on input elements to execute a function to manipulate the user input into the format that you are looking for on each change.

```
    function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.valueEntered = '';
        $scope.value = '';

        $scope.valueEnteredChanged = function () {
            // more robust logic here
            $scope.value = $scope.valueEntered * 100;
        }
    }
```

and with markup that looks like this.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="valueEntered" ng-change="valueEnteredChanged()" /><br />
    <span ng-bind="valueEntered"></span><br />
    <span ng-bind="value"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best method I can think of without writing a more complex directive, and this method is certainly simpler!

Comment: Thanks, I actually wrote something similar before I saw this, but without the two span elements.  Are those necessary?

Comment: No, they are not necessary. I just added them for you to be able to see what values get stored inside the individual scope items.

Answer (score 4):

Found out how to do this with a directive using NgModelController from this page http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

Basically, the following directive would multiply/divid by 100 for an input field with transformTest as an attribute.

```
merchantApp.directive('transformTest', function() {
  return { restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel) return;

      ngModel.$render = function () {
        element.val(ngModel.$viewValue / 100);
      }

      element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
        scope.$apply(read);
        ngModel.$render();
      }); 

      read();

      function read() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val() * 100);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

$watch the model/dollar value and keep a cents property in synch:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('dollars', function(dollars) {
        $scope.cents = $scope.dollars * 100;
    })
}​
```

Markup:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="dollars">
<br>{{dollars}} {{cents}}
```

Comment: If using this approach, I'd probably include another $watch going in the other direction (even if I didn't currently have any other code modifying the `cents` variable) to avoid future code bringing the `cents` and `dollars` variables out of sync - which the implementation shown here permits.

Comment: Note that this approach also costs you performance, since the `input`-element will update the `dollars` variable on the scope, it will cause a digest-cycle to update the `cents` variable. This will in turn then cause another digest-cycle. Using the `$parsers` and `$formatters` approach in @gingermusketeer's answer prevents this extra cycle, because the value is converted before it is written to the scope.