# AngularJS - Formatting ng-model before template is rendered in custom directive

Tags: templates, model, angularjs, directive

I am creating a custom directive in Angular JS. And I want to format the ng-model before the template renders.

This is what I have so far:

app.js

```
app.directive('editInPlace', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { ngModel: '=' },
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" my-date-picker disabled>'
    };
});
```

html

```
<edit-in-place ng-model="unformattedDate"></edit-in-place>
```

I want to format the unformattedDate value before it is entered in the ngModel of the template. Something like this:

```
template: '<input type="text" ng-model="formatDate(ngModel)" my-date-picker disabled>'
```

but that gives me an error. How to do this?

Answer (score 25):

`ngModel` exposes its controller [`ngModelController` API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController) and offers you a way to do so.

In your directive, you can add [`$formatters`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) that do exactly what you need and [`$parsers`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers), that do the other way around (parse the value before it goes to the model).

This is how you should go:

```js
app.directive('editInPlace', function($filter) {
  var dateFilter = $filter('dateFormat');

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { ngModel: '=' },
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$formatters.unshift(function(valueFromModel) {
        // what you return here will be passed to the text field
        return dateFilter(valueFromModel);
      });

      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(valueFromInput) {
        // put the inverse logic, to transform formatted data into model data
        // what you return here, will be stored in the $scope
        return ...;
      });
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" my-date-picker disabled>'
  };
});
```

Comment: where did you get $filter? is it necessary to pass that to the function? I am using a formatter in the global scope to format the date. so my current paramater is $rootScope

Comment: The valueFromModel variable also returns undefined. am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The `$filter` is injected, as I thought you were using it. If not, just inject `$rootScope` and reach to the filter. About the `valueFromModel`, it's possible that the value is `null` at the start, so return either `null` or ''.

Comment: The order how the filter and parser chain is called is also important if different conversions on the value should be performe. The parser chain is called with the view value starting at array index 0, the formatter chain is called with the model value starting at array index 0. That is why `unshift` is used for the formatters and `push` is used for the parsers.