# AngularJS: input type=number" parse ngModel string value to number and back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am pretty new to angularJs. My problem is:

My model data are kept in a database and if a project is reopened the data is displayed. With save the data are stored again in the database. I have a problem with displaying the number with
 since the value is stored as a string and must be parsed to an integer.

Here is the html:

```
 <numeric-input numericbinding="item.showInt" ng-model="item.operandvalue" ></numeric-input>
```

Depending on the format of the item value (bool, int, string), the operandvalue is displayed in different ways. This is directed with the value of numericbinding.

I tried to use the following directive to parse the string to an int:

```
.directive('numericInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel',
            numericbinding: '='
        },
        template: '<input id="integerType" type="number" ng-model="intValue" ng-hide="!numericbinding" >',
        link: function (scope) {
            //avoid that string and bool is parsed,  showInt is false
            if (scope.numericbinding === false || scope.numericbinding === undefined) {
                return;
            }

           scope.intValue = parseInt(scope.model, 10);

        }
    };
})
```

This way the number is displayed correctly. But if I want to store my data again for the bound item.operandvalue I get a Nullpointer in the backend. I understand that I need to convert the number back to a string. I tried multiple ways,e.g.

- ng-change: But it never got in the given function.

Then I wanted to use ngModelController with formatter and parser as described in [AngularJS - Formatting ng-model before template is rendered in custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901889/angularjs-formatting-ng-model-before-template-is-rendered-in-custom-directive)

```
.directive('numericInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel',
            numericbinding: '='
        },
        template: '<input id="integerType" type="number" ng-model="item.operandvalue" ng-hide="!numericbinding" >',
        link: function (scope, ngModelController) {
            //avoid that string and bool is parsed,  showInt is false
            if (scope.numericbinding === false || scope.numericbinding === undefined) {
                //console.log('not a number - return');
                return;
            }

            ngModelController.$formatters.unshift(function(valueFromModel) {
                return parseInt(valueFromModel, 10);
           });

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(valueFromInput) {
                return valueFromInput.toString();
            });

        }
    };
})
```

However, the valueFromModel is undefined. The number is not displayed at all. Also scope.item.operandvalue is undefined. In Chrome the error is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'operandvalue' of undefined.

I think that I should keep the item.operandvalue, which is data bound, as a string and display the int value with a different name. In my first way it seems that item.operandvalue gets a number and the data binding does not work any longer.

How can I fix my problem? Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use two fields: backing_field and binding_field. When the db is read you write to the backing_field. This could then be used to update the binding_field, e.g. via $watch. You can use two watches to keep them in sync. In case one changes, you convert its value and write it to the other. You might now argue that his will create a loop, but AngularJS detects that nothing changes and will not fire again. Using this, you can update the backing_field, when the binding_field changes due to user interaction and update the binding_field through the backing_field when you get new data from the database.