# Anything similar to WPF's ValueConverters for AngularJS?

Tags: wpf, angularjs

Is there anything in Value Converters with Convert and Convert Back functionality in AngularJS?

Comment: Angular has a built in Filter Service which lets you do some basic conversions (see:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter) or u can build your own custom filter

Comment: ok., but is it possible to implement convert and convert back (for two way binding) by using filters?

Comment: you may have a look at this related Questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616636/how-to-do-two-way-filtering-in-angular-js OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885172/how-to-create-a-composite-filter-with-two-way-binding

Comment: see also [Is it possible to transform a value between view and model in AngularJS for input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13420693/1271037)